# Can scars be "shown" or "taken"?

Tags: verb-usage

Do we normally use "show" and "take" for scars?

> He pressed his lips with irritation, which **showed** the dark scar on the corner of his mouth he **had taken** while shaving, more strongly.

Comment: Is this a sentence that you wrote or that you found somewhere? Please note the source. :)

Comment: I wrote it myself.

Comment: I would use *gotten* here.  *Received* is sometimes used as well, particularly when a scar is gotten through the actions of another person (ex: a soldier or police officer's wound.)  You might also see a reflexive action like *given himself* used to highlight clumsiness in a slightly humorous way.

Comment: I wouldn't say he (got/received/gave himself) a scar _while_ shaving at all.   He gave himself a cut while shaving; the scar came later.  _He pressed his lips with irritation, revealing a dark scar on the corner of his mouth where he had cut himself shaving the week before._  Corner of his mouth, though?  I picture that being the crease where the upper and lower lips meet - not a spot that is exposed by pressing one's lips together.  Perhaps  _He pressed his lips with irritation, revealing a dark scar on his lip where he had cut himself shaving the week before._

Answer (score 1):

No, we don't usually speak of "taking" a scar.  I would say it was a scar he got while shaving or a scar he received while shaving.

Using "show" as part of the phrase "showed... more strongly" is also not a common wording.  It's also better (easier to understand) if you can bring the parts of that descriptive phrase together.  It might be better to say something like, He pressed his lips with irritation, making the dark shaving scar on the corner of his mouth show more (strongly -- change, maybe, to clearly or prominently)